# how to insert a char* into the end of a vector<char>?

Tags: c++

```cpp
vector<char> vec;
vec.push_back(0x1);
char* a = "qwe";
```

I want to push `a` to the end of the vector.

Comment: Ok, you've showed that you know how to `push_back` one `char` at a time. So, what exactly is unclear about `push_back`ing three characters? You just do the same thing, three times?

Comment: Be careful: a pointer is not an array. You're not looking to insert that pointer into the vector; you're looking to insert the text that it points at into the vector.

Comment: `char* a = "qwe"` This is ill-formed since C++11.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.insert()` member function with pointers standing in as iterators.

```
vec.insert(vec.end(), a, a+strlen(a));
```